# If the chord $x+y=b$ of the curve ...

Tags: analytic-geometry

If the chord $x+y=b$ of the curve $x^2+y^2-2ax-4a^2=0$ subtends a right angle at the origin, prove that: $b(b-a)=4a^2$

My Approach.

Given,

Equation of the chord,
$$x+y=b$$
$$\frac {x+y}{b}=1$$

Now,

Equation of the curve,
$$x^2+y^2-2ax-4a^2=0$$
$$x^2+y^2-2ax=4a^2$$
$$(b-y)^2+(b-x)^2-2ax=4a^2$$

I got stuck at here. Please help me to complete it.

Comment: What does "subtends...whatever... *at the origin* " mean?? I can understand that if "we look" at the cord from **any** point on the circle then "subtending an angle at that point" means the inscribed angle determined by that point and that cord. Yet the origin is *not* a point on the circle...

Comment: @DonAntonio, I, too could not understand the question. However, the question is absolutely correct as given.

Comment: Then it must be me not acquainted enough with the terms used here.

Comment: @DonAntonio, It might be. I am too, unclear with the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio it just means the lines from the origin to the endpoints of the chord are perpendicular.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thanks, that sounds plausible...but never met it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined equation of the lines joining the origin to the end points of the chord can be obtained by "homogenising" the equation of the curve. This is 
\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2 - 2ax\left(\frac{x+y}{b}\right) - 4a^2\left(\frac{x+y}{b}\right)^2 = 0 
\end{align*}
These lines are perpendicular if the sum of the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ is zero. Thus the required condition is 
\begin{align*}
1+1-\frac{2a}{b}-\frac{4a^2}{b^2}(1+1) &= 0\\
b^2 - ab -4a^2 &= 0\\
b(b-a) &= 4a^2
\end{align*}

Comment: What is meant by homogenising?

Comment: @user354073 If we have an equation of a curve as $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c = 0$ and a line $lx+my=1$, the equation of the pair of lines joining the origin and  the end points of $lx+my=1$ on the curve can be obtained as $ax^2+2hxy+by^2 +2(gx+fy)(lx+my) + c(lx+my)^2 = 0$. Note that we have "created" a homogeneous equation of second degree from the curve and the line and hence it represents a pair of lines through the origin. It is easy to see that the points of intersection of the curve and line lie on this. This process is called "homogenising".

Comment: Also for a pair of lines $Ax^2+2Hxy+By^2 = 0$ through the origin, they are perpendicular if $A+B=0$.

Comment: It means, homogenising is to be done in the last three terms of a general equation of the curve. Is it?

Comment: The aim is to make each term of second degree. So we need to multiply linear terms by $lx+my$ and the constant terms by $(lx+my)^2$.

Comment: How did you do $(1+1)$ while writing the perpendicularity condition?

Comment: Coefficient of $x^2$ is 1, coefficient of $y^2$ is 1 in the first two terms, in the third term, only $x^2$ is present with coefficient $-2a/b$ and in the last term we have $x^2$ term with coefficient $-4a^2/b^2$ and $y^2$ term also has the same coefficient. We add all these and equate to zero.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks a lot. It was nice talking to you.

Answer (score 2):

First solve the equations simultaneously, and we arrive at the quadratic equation $$2x^2-2x(a+b)+b^2-4a^2=0$$

The roots satisfy $$x_1+x_2=a+b$$ and $$x_1x_2=\frac{b^2-4a^2}{2}$$

The perpendicularity condition can be written as $$x_1x_2+y_1y_2=0$$

$$\implies x_1x_2+(b-x_1)(b-x_2)=0$$
$$\implies 2x_1x_2-b(x_1+x_2)+b^2=0$$

Using the above results for the sum and product of the roots, the result follows immediately.

Comment: What do you mean by sum and products of the roots? I could not understand. Please elaborate it.

Comment: The quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The sum of the roots is $\alpha+\beta=-\frac ba$ and the product of roots is $\alpha\beta=\frac ca$

Comment: How did you get the quadratic equation at the beginning of your solution?

Comment: By substituting $y=b-x$ into the curve equation

Comment: How did you get the perpendicularity condition?

Comment: The product of perpendicular gradients is$-1$

Comment: And how is that condition equal to zero?

Comment: write down the gradient of the line joining the origin to $(x_1,y_1)$ and likewise for the other line. Product of gradients is $-1$.